# Optical Character Recognition with Python - Auto Cropping

Tags: python, image, ocr, photos

I am working on various OCR tasks, pre-processing with Python and analyzing with Tesseract.

The latest problem is how to crop an image with images within e.g. a scanned image of 6 business cards or a photo of a board with two distinct sections.  I would like to turn said business cards on one image (.jpg, .png) into 6 images.

Ideally, I would like to do this in Python (R as well), but I'm open to any and all suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using opencv you may be abile to find their contours, like they do in [their documentation about finding contours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html#gsc.tab=0).

I also wrote a grid detector, if your card are all the same size, it may be a source of inspiration, if they're not, it may be a source of inspiration too ... https://github.com/julienpalard/grid-finder

Comment: Thanks Julien.  I have been working with finding contours, but it doesn't seem to help in my case.  Indeed, I think your code with help inspire next steps.  The "grids" are all over the place (vary greatly from one image to the other).